# Calculating days between two dates in JAVA (catch ParseException error)

Tags: java, date, date-format, parseexception

I’m trying to calculate the number of days between 2 dates. When I run this, it throws the **catch (ParseException ex).**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date1 = "11/11/2020";
        String date2 = "13/11/2020";

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
            Date date_1 = dateFormat.parse(date1);
            Date date_2 = dateFormat.parse(date2);

            System.out.println(date_1);
            System.out.println(date_2);

            long numberOfDays = date_2.getTime() - date_1.getTime();
            numberOfDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(numberOfDays, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            System.out.println(numberOfDays);

        } 
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

other than the catch, there are no errors, so I’m kind of lost.

Comment: "other than the catch, there are no errors, so I’m kind of lost."... well, should you maybe print what the exception says?

Comment: Change date strings to use '-' instead of '/' eg. "11-11-2020". Or change the SimpleDateFormat string to look like this: "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Statement "it throws the catch (ParseException ex)" is really weird. By it's nature a "catch" block catches the exception, not throws it (well, you can rethrow something inside of it). It is recommended to properly handle the caught expection, eg. at least use `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println("error");`

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, `Date` is quite `deprecated` and should not be used.  `LocalDate` is the way to go for date related code.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Also converting milliseonds to days may give inaccurate results across summer time (DST) transistions and similar. Instead use `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Date.  Try this.

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date1 = "11/11/2020";
        String date2 = "13/11/2020";

        LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse(date1,dtf);
        LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse(date2,dtf);

        long ndays = d1.datesUntil(d2).count();
        System.out.println(ndays);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you had printed the catched exception:

```
System.out.println("error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
```

You would have seen:

```
error: Unparseable date: "11/11/2020"
```

The problem is in:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

change it to:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Since the provided dates are in that format.

Comment: According to the JavaDoc, `mm` stands for minutes.

Comment: @WJS You are right, well spotted, it had more than one bug then. I update the answer, thanks

Comment: java.time would have made you aware of the incorrect case of `mm`. One more reason to use it instead of the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

Just change this :

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

to that :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The date you are trying to parse `11/11/2020` does not match the date format you are trying to use `dd-mm-yyyy`

You can resolve problems like that on your own by printing out the stack trace inside catch :

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: change mm to MM (minutes to Month).

Answer (score 3):

If Java 8 is an option I'd recommend using the Time API.

Example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date1 = "11/11/2020";
        String date2 = "13/11/2020";

        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(date1, format);
        LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(date2, format);

        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate);
        System.out.println("Days between: " + days);
    }
}
```

Comment: @WJS beat me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

First, you have different formats in input dates and defined format. Therefore, you're getting a parsing exception.

Secondly, We can `java.time.Duration` class in Java8 for such calculation. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String date1 = "11/11/2020";
    String date2 = "13/11/2020";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Duration duration = Duration.between(format.parse(date1).toInstant(), format.parse(date2).toInstant());
    System.out.println("Days between: " + duration.toDays());
}
```

Comment: I agree that using java.time since Java 8 is a great improvement. Still better: (1) Drop the use of the old `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` completely. (2) Use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` rather than `Duration`. BTW lower case `mm` is incorrect for month.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V
1 & 2  are good suggestions
3) `mm` is working fine with `SimpleDateFormat ` but not work in `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Oooh! My bad. I did not notice that. You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is incorrect.

You use:

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");`

but you need use:

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");`

because yours date's have "/" instead of "-"